# Device UDID is already present in my developer account still getting the error as waiting for developer in firebase and fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I am trying to build the app and upload to firebase through fastlane.

Add distributed successfully, but after the distribution the app shows the Waiting for developer and need to add the UDID.

But already I have added that UDId of the user in my provisioning profiles?

How this will be happen?

Answer (score 1):

Not fully understanding the context here but whenever I ran in a similar issue I need to archive the build once again making sure it gets the updated provisioning profile.

Also, if you use SIGH and you want all your devices being added automatically, every build I recommend using `force` option.

http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/#parameters

Answer (score 1):

For firebase distribution using the fastlane, I need to set the adhoc certificate. The above issue got because I have distributed the app using AppStore provisioning profile.

Added the export_method as Adhoc and run the build it get succeeded and able to install the app on my phone.